# Pass information of html/php form using c# webservice

Tags: c#, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, web-services

My HTML/Bootstrap form is this one:

```
<form role="form" action="" method="post" class="login-form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Email</label>
        <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Email....."
               class="form-username form-control" id="form-email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-text">Type Order</label>
        <input type="text" name="form-text" placeholder="Tipo Encomenda"
               class="form-text form-control" id="form-text">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-number">Number</label>
        <input type="number" min="0" max="150" name="form-number"
               placeholder="Numero Peças" class="form-number form-control"
               id="form-number">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="form-radio">Urgen</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Urgente</label>
        <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio">Não
            Urgente</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

And I want to send the results by c# webservice to a program that uses this method. I don't know if is possible directly or using a txt and after get the info.

Comment: you can specify the target in form action

Comment: I have posted an answer

Answer (score 0):

This way

```
<form role="form" action="demo_form.asp" method="post" class="login-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="form-username">Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="form-username" placeholder="Email....."
           class="form-username form-control" id="form-email">
  </div>
   .........
```

or

```
 <form role="form" action="mytest.php " method="post" class="login-form">
```

or any web target youwant send the data by http post method

for a web service  GetDetailsService.asmx/GetCustdet

```
  <form role="form" action="mGetDetailsService.asmx/GetCustdet" method="post" class="login-form">
```

and you can see a sample here (is for ajax  but the concept is similar) http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/calling-web-service-in-html-page2/

Comment: But how can the, in this case, the website know where the webservice are?

Comment: Normaly in pathname or the action eg: or in post param is setted the webservice action to execute .. eg: in some case you can see  a path like demo_form.asp/create  or mytest.php/index

Comment: But, for example, I need to publish the Web Service or put tje webservice locally in inetpub

Comment: thank you, from the side of the web service how can i collect the data from the html form?